# d3.js: tooltip and attribute change on mouseover

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip

I've integrated [tooltips by Caged](http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/) in my d3 visualization ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ec7Lbaxf/)). They are called simply with

```
.on("mouseover", tip.show)
.on("mouseout", tip.hide)
```

Now I've found I can't add other mouseover functionalities such as changing the size and colour of the object I'm pointing the mouse at. Either the tooltips or the attribute changes are shown when I try something like this:

```
on("mouseover", function(d){
 tip.show;
 d3.select(this).attr("r", 10).style("fill", "orange");
})
.on("mouseout", function(d){
 tip.hide;
 d3.select(this).attr("r", 6).style("fill", "red");
})
```

How can I show both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the tooltip functions:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d){
  tip.show(d);
  d3.select(this).attr("r", 10).style("fill", "orange");
}).on("mouseout", function(d){
  tip.hide(d);
  d3.select(this).attr("r", 6).style("fill", "red");
})
```

`tip.show` and `tip.hide` are functions and adding parentheses after the name means that you're calling them. This isn't necessary when not using an anonymous function (i.e. `function() { ... }`) because D3 knows that a function is being passed and should be called (i.e. evaluated) at runtime. In short, D3 calls the function passed as an argument automatically.

Comment: Oh thanks. Well, another dumb question, why does tip.show work (if only on its own)?

Comment: Thanks. Coming from Java, JavaScript's often lax rules confuse me sometimes. Actually if I use `tip.show()` in my own code in conjunction with changing size and colour, this happens: `TypeError: d is undefined` and no tooltip is shown. I need to use `tip.show(d)` as mzulch proposed. Do you have an idea why? I updated the fiddle so that data is bound to the circles, but the tooltip functions still work without argument https://jsfiddle.net/ec7Lbaxf/2/

Comment: Ah yes -- `d` is the data bound to the element, and if you need that in the tooltip (i.e. you want to show something defined in the data), you need to pass it. I've updated the answer. In the case where you just give the function name, the arguments are passed automatically.

Comment: Oh yeah that makes perfect sense, hadn't thought of `d` being accessed at another place in the code where the tooltip content is defined. Again, thanks for your help. As a d3 noob I wonder why it is even possible to call a function without parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

When you wrap the tip.show function in a closure instead of just passing it in directly as the callback, you need to call it like any other function

```
on("mouseover", function(d){
 tip.show(d);
})
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ejddhdpb